# angular 4 add authentication against azure mobile app with adal.js token

Tags: angular, active-directory, azure-mobile-services, adal.js

I'm developing an angular 4 app with adal.js and azure mobile apps client for js.
I'm integrating this app with my mobile app backend in an updated version of Adrian Hall's zumo book, chapter 6, to angular 4.

I successfully login using adal, and have the token, but when I try this:

```
msclient.login('aad', { 'access_token': token })
```

I get a 401 error: "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

If I use the server flow: `msclient.login('aad')` , a popup window opens & closes right away and the login operation succeeds without having to enter anything. (I believe the token is being sent along with the request). I would like to login silently in the backend, since I already have the token. What am I missing ?

Thanks
Aline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, it seems that you were passing the incorrect token.

Please check the app you protect the mobile back-end. By default you can pass the id_token acquire using that app to the mobile back-end to use the client flow. And if you were passing the access_token, we need to config the **ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES** by using **Advanced** mode like figure below:
[image]

Refer the figure below:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ai1yePW-i2GvhMV_H3zW94o4DBih_Q

Comment: The image service for Stack Overflow forum seems down. Please check the settings and token described in the post and I have update the figure to third-party web site and feel free to let me know if you still have the problem. And

Comment: Hi!
I've checked that setting. I've got 
https://<myMobileAppName>.azurewebsites.net, which is the same my web app is using, because everything is published together. 
As for the token, I've been following this post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2/  and the token I'm sending is AdalService.accessToken

Comment: You can decode the access token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) and check whether the `aud` claim is config in the **ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES** on the mobile app.

Comment: Thanks @FeiXue !
I did what you suggested and found out that the `aud` was holding my webapp Application ID from AAD, instead of the url. I then added it to the allowed token audiences of my mobile app and everything works :)